# Trying to create a route with two parallel lines with postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, qgis

So I just started working with SQL and PostGIS. For this exercise I need to create a table with a primary key and a geometry field.

```
Insert into paradezug Values (1,ST_Transform( st_linefromtext('linestring(13.40044325726135 52.51884104088853 , 13.40109986093854 52.51827594967714)',4326),25833));

Insert into paradezug Values (2,ST_Transform( st_linefromtext('LineString(13.40109986093854 52.51827594967714 , 13.39917356833286 52.51769543984515)',4326),25833));

Insert into paradezug Values (3,ST_Transform( st_linefromtext('linestring(13.39917356833286 52.51769543984515 , 13.37837611723877 52.5162977964313)',4326),25833));
```

This worked well and gave me the route which I can import and view in QGIS.

Now I have to add a line on the left and on the right with a 250m offset.

I've tried:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_OffsetCurve(geom,
    -250, 'quad_segs=4 join=round')) As notsocurvy
    FROM ST_GeomFromText(
'linestring(13.40044325726135 52.51884104088853 , 13.40109986093854 52.51827594967714)') As geom;

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_OffsetCurve(geom,
    -250, 'quad_segs=4 join=round')) As notsocurvy
    FROM ST_GeomFromText(
'LineString(13.40109986093854 52.51827594967714 , 13.39917356833286 52.51769543984515)') As geom;

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_OffsetCurve(geom,
    -250, 'quad_segs=4 join=round')) As notsocurvy
    FROM ST_GeomFromText(
'linestring(13.39917356833286 52.51769543984515 , 13.37837611723877 52.5162977964313)') As geom;
```

Which returned *something* successful. But as I'm new to SQL I don't quite understand how to move on from here.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `ST_OffsetCurve` outputs a new geometry derived from an existing one.

You started by computing the curve offset using a column name, and this column comes from a manually created geometry:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_OffsetCurve(geom,
    -250, 'quad_segs=4 join=round')) As notsocurvy
FROM ST_GeomFromText(
'linestring(13.39917356833286 52.51769543984515 , 13.37837611723877 52.5162977964313)') As geom;
```

If you want to derive the curve from your table, you can reference it here:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_OffsetCurve(geom,
    -250, 'quad_segs=4 join=round')) As notsocurvy
FROM paradezug ;
```

From there, one option is to add the curve offset to the same table. The `id` should be populated by a sequence (search for `serial` or `identity`) so you can simply omit it in the `insert` statements. Also, you don't need to insert a text but a geometry, so let's remove the `st_asText` function:

```sql
INSERT INTO paradezug (geom)
SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom,
        -250, 'quad_segs=4 join=round') As geom
FROM paradezug ;
```

Now you may want to track which line is the center line and to ensure the offset lines do not exist yet before running this query.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to only select the first two rows from the table with
"
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
"
?

Comment: @Katerkaskade forget about `row_number()` for now, most of the time it is not needed. To select the 2 first row (ids 1 and 2), add a `where` clause (`where id <= 2`)